# Address watcher with BDK/Rust

Tags: watch-only, output-script-descriptors, bitcoin-development-kit

I'm trying to implement (multiple) address watcher in BDK/Rust.

1. I'm having trouble doing this for an arbitrary address, because BDK and rust-miniscript don't support "addr()" expressions in an output descriptor. Is there any way around to create a watch-only wallet from a single address?
2. Is BDK and descriptor wallets even a good choice for monitoring a list of unrelated addresses? Are there any more suitable alternatives...?